# Podfile PXGoogleDirections and GoogleMaps conflicting names

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to install a new pod (PXGoogleDirections) to my already existing xcode project which already had a GoogleMaps pod installed.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Roadtrip' do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'PXGoogleDirections'
end

target 'RoadtripTests' do

end

target 'RoadtripUITests' do

end
```

When I run "pod install" I'm getting the error: "[!] The 'PROJECT' target has frameworks with conflicting names: GoogleMaps."

Any idea how I can fix that?

I've already tried to use the same GoogleMaps version as PXGoogleDirections uses, like so:

```
pod 'GoogleMaps', '1.10.4'
```

but I'm getting the same error.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Posted an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453410/how-to-fix-framework-with-conflicting-names-in-cocoapods/39465955#39465955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `PXGoogleDirections` itself is bundled with `GoogleMaps`. In the documentation of `PXGoogleDirections` says the way to use googlemaps with it.
Check this

> If your app also requires the Google Maps iOS SDK, you might run into
>   troubles because of conflicts with the bundled Google Maps iOS SDK in
>   the Cocoapod. If you happen to face these problems, please try to do
>   the following:
>
> Add -framework "GoogleMaps" to the "Other Linker Flags" of your Xcode
>   project. Make sure you are linking your app with all the libraries and
>   frameworks required by the Google Maps iOS SDK. For a full list, see
>   here:
>   https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/GoogleMaps/1.10.4/GoogleMaps.podspec.json
>   Also make sure that your app contains the GoogleMaps.bundle in the
>   "Copy Bundle Resources" phase of the build process. If it doesn't, you
>   can manually add it to Xcode by browsing to the following directory in
>   the Finder:
>   /Pods/PXGoogleDirections/Dependencies/GoogleMaps.framework/Resources/GoogleMaps.bundle.
>   Drop it in the "Frameworks" group of your project and uncheck the
>   "Copy" checkbox.

Direct Link https://github.com/poulpix/PXGoogleDirections#in-case-of-problems

Comment: I've missed that. Thanks.

Comment: Hey all - did you get this working without any warnings? As of right now the pod is working, but I get a ton of warnings in when I build and run: `objc[1774]: Class GMSBillingPointRecorder is implemented in both path/to/myapp.app/Frameworks/PXGoogleDirections.framework/PXGoogleDirections and path/to/myapp.app/myapp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.` There is one warning for every class in the GoogleMaps framework.

Comment: please do a deep clean and build.

Comment: @Mayko Hey, have you managed to do this? Do I add it under the Debug or Release category?

Comment: I'm still getting the error after following the said instructions! Any additional steps to be done?