# How to fix framework with conflicting names in Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

I have created two private pods which both relies on a same vendor framework. When I add the pods into my main project I get below error:

```
target has frameworks with conflicting names: FirebaseAnalytics, FirebaseInstanceID, GoogleInterchangeUtilities, GoogleSymbolUtilities, and GoogleUtilities.
```

I tried with both cocoapods 0.39 and version 1.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Cocoapod 1.0.1. To solve this untill they fix beta, I used:

```
pod _1.0.0_ install
```

Comment: do you know if this was fixed for 1.1.1?